# How to make LibGDX + Android Studio jar file?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I can't find a way to create an Android Studio jar file for Desktop. I am using Android Studio 1.3.2 and LibGDX library. I created a video game and I want to share it with other PC's without having to install Android Studio to run my project.

What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you still have got a build.gradle file for the desktop configuration, execute the "dist" build configuration via gradle. As a result, a runnable jar file will be created.

If you do not know how to achieve this in Android Studio, this can be easily done from the command prompt:

- swich to your projects directory
- `./gradlew desktop:dist`

Comment: THANK YOU SIR! I LOVE YOU!!

Comment: Express your love by marking the answer as correct, if it helped.

Comment: So in Android Studio, I assume we go to console, change directly to the projects directory, and run gradlew desktop:dist?  That would never work. Could you possibly expand on your two lines? I'm basically doing this incorrectly.

 `$ gradlew desktop:dist`  

Response: `bash: gradlew: command not found`  I checked out https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-on-the-Commandline  I guess we need to add a desktop folder to the Android project in order to make this work.  I liked the idea of compiling the app into a JAR file and having it run in Windows.

Comment: You go to the console, change to the root directory of your project and type the gradlewcommand

Comment: I figured it out.  Go to the terminal tab in Android studio, and specifically use the following command: `./gradlew desktop:dist`  Just having `gradlew desktop:dist` alone isn't good enough.  Needed the period and backslash in there. Was copying and pasting the command from the answer thinking it would work as is.  All is well, thank you.